# Converting flat JSON into a nested JSON grouping by common key names

Tags: json, jq

I was using JQPlay to play around the format. I am not able to understand how to use reduce to group by child structure. I want to group based on the org or the parent id.

just update my jqplay filter, but not able to remove two tags to group by id.

#### jq play syntax-

I am using below syntax in jqplay.org. Also can you please advise how debug anything after pipe symbol.

```
.items | {"org" : map( {id : .org, orgProperties : [{"properties" : {"methodId" : [{"id" : .methodId}]}}]})| group_by(.id) | map( reduce .[] as $x (.[0]|{}; .orgProperties+= ($x | .orgProperties)))}
```

### Input JSON

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "org": "750141",
      "methodId": "1-10F7IAK7"
    },
    {
      "org": "750141",
      "methodId": "1-10TP18L0"
    },
    {
      "org": "750142",
      "methodId": "1-10TP18L1"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Output JSON

```
{
  "org": [
    {
      "orgProperties": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "methodId": [
              {
                "id": "1-10F7IAK7"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "methodId": [
              {
                "id": "1-10TP18L0"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "orgProperties": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "methodId": [
              {
                "id": "1-10TP18L1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

### Expected JSON Output

```
{
  "org": [
    {
      "id": "750141",
      "orgProperties": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "methodId": [
              {
                "id": "1-10F7IAK7"
              },
              {
                "id": "1-10TP18L0"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
        {
      "id": "750142",
      "orgProperties": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "methodId": [
              {
                "id": "1-10TP18L1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like below. You need to `group_by()` and then later do the processing

```
jq '.items | {org: group_by(.org) | map({id: .[0].org, orgProperties: [{properties: { methodId: map({id: .methodId}) }}]})} ' input.json
```

I don't think there exists a way to increase the debug verbose level thrown by `jq` unless probably tinkering with the code to add your own debug statements and run a custom build.

I personally build-up the filter from one component at a time, observe its output and manipulate things on top of that. To break down the functionality of above

- The JSON is reconstructed completely after the `'.items | {org: ..` portion of the filter. The result of the subsequent part forms what is now below the top level `"org"` section the expected output.
- Once you do a `group_by(.org)`, you get a result that has two array entries, one with 2 objects (id `750141`) and the other with a single object (id `750142`).
- Then you run the code inside `map(..)` to the object list returned from the previous step
- We only need the unique key name in the final result, so we just use the `.[0].org` in the first array. This will work even you have multiple repetitive key names. Pause and have a look at the output until this point

  ```
  {
    "org": [
      {
        "id": "750141"
      },
      {
        "id": "750142"
      }
    ]
  }
  ```
- Now construct the rest of the output with `orgProperties: [{properties: { methodId: ...` which creates the sub-nodes as

  ```
  "orgProperties": [
  {
      "properties": {
          "methodId":
  ```
- Create the final sub array with `map({id: .methodId})` to create a key value pair with the list of IDs

Comment: Thanks mate.  It worked and great thing is i understood how it is done now. But can you explain why do we use .[0] ... what does it implies.

Comment: @user2993735: After the `group_by(.org)`, two arrays are created, the first one with same value `.org` as `750141`. So we are reducing this two into one by using the `.[0]` which is same as doing `.[1]`. See the output of `.items | {org: group_by(.org)}` and see for it yourself.